# Cache-Control is not respected in ASP.NET Core Middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this middleware:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains("image/resize"))
    {
        context.Response.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "max-age=31536000";
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
        context.Response.Headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache";
        context.Response.Headers["Expires"] = "0";
    }
    await next.Invoke();
});
```

The problem is that when I request an image, I get this response header:

> cache-control: public,max-age=30

If I request an API that returns JSON, the `else` block works. Cache headers are set correctly.

But for images that are served, the cache is not set correctly.

What might be wrong? How can I fix this?

**Update**

These are my codes after this middleware in the pipeline:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseMvc(options =>
{
    options.MapRoute("Default", "{controller=Default}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: Is it possible that something overrides your settings later in the pipeline?

Comment: @GuruStron, I updated the question. After this middleware, I only use authentication and authorization, and the `UseMvc`.

Comment: Examine the response AFTER the `next.Invoke()`.  Remember, this is a pipeline, so you could actually put the code after the next.Invoke, if anything IS overriding it further along the pipeline.

Comment: @Neil, I can't put the code after the `next.Invoke()` because it throws an error and complains that the response is already started and headers are read-only.

Comment: Where do you apply the middleware? Order matters. Middleware is called in the order it's defined

Answer (score 1):

The correct order should be like below:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseMvc(options =>
{
    options.MapRoute("Default", "{controller=Default}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains("image/resize"))
    {
        context.Response.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "max-age=31536000";
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
        context.Response.Headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache";
        context.Response.Headers["Expires"] = "0";
    }
    await next.Invoke();
});
```

Comment: Made no difference.

Comment: @Bigboy Could you share us the sample project(without any sensitive info), so that we could check the issue deeply.

Comment: It's solved. I had a `ResponseCache` on my controller and I did not know that. It was overriding my middleware.